# Robocopy error: ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Changing File Attributes

Tags: robocopy, windows-11

Ugh.  I've been using this command for *years* and am now getting this error:

robocopy m:\ e:\ /MIR /MT /R:1 /W:10 /XD m:$RECYCLE.BIN m:\temp\Backup  m:.TemporaryItems "m:\System Volume Information" m:\Ignore /LOG+:m:\backup-log.txt /TEE

2022/01/13 19:18:37 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Changing File Attributes E:\

Basically I'm mirroring the contents from the M: drive to the E: drive.  Both M and E drives are drive pools.  I was using Drive Bender for the drive pool, but they don't support WSL on Windows 11 right now.  So, I switched to StableBit DrivePool software.    So to answer the inevitable question, yes I am running Windows 11.  *This command worked before on Windows 11*

I checked with IACLS and both the M: drive and E: drive appear to be exactly the same:

M:>icacls m:
m:\ BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

M:>icacls e:
e:\ BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

The drive pools are quite large (like 41 TB) so just copying with xcopy is not really an option.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Have you tried changing file attributes at the root of E: simply from cmd.exe?  I would be curious to know if that worked.

Comment: Silly me. I spent a day fighting this. Then something struck me - this is a drive pool (using StableBit DrivePool) - maybe it’s showing me more info. It was. The pool was missing two drives in the pool, DrivePool was doing its job on the pool. Fixed the error on the two drives (power problem on one of the arrays I use) and all seems to be well now.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. I spent a day fighting this. Then something struck me - this is a drive pool (using StableBit DrivePool) - maybe it’s showing me more info. It was. The pool was missing two drives in the pool, DrivePool was doing its job on the pool. Fixed the error on the two drives (power problem on one of the arrays I use) and all seems to be well now.